# how to remove sub node from Javascript Dom

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have an XML node called *MainNode*. Inside this node I have four other nodes, NodeOne until NodeFour. How do I only remove Node 2 and 3 from the MainNode?

**Part two of my question**:  it is possible to remove MainNode and SubNodes 2 and 3 without removing Nodes 1 and 4?
Below is the XML for my question:

```
<MainNode>
    <NodeOne>one</NodeOne>
    <NodeTow>tow</NodeTow>
    <NodeThree>Thre</NodeThree>
    <NodeFour>Four</NodeFour>
</MainNode>
```

Comment: MainNode.children[1].remove();MainNode.children[1].remove(); would remove two and three

Comment: can u tell me Js Code to doing it

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then standard DOM manipulation.

Part 1

```js
var xml = '<MainNode><NodeOne>one</NodeOne><NodeTow>tow</NodeTow><NodeThree>Three</NodeThree><NodeFour>Four</NodeFour></MainNode>',
    doc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml'),
    NodeTow = doc.querySelector('NodeTow'),
    NodeThree = doc.querySelector('NodeThree');

NodeTow.parentElement.removeChild(NodeTow);
NodeThree.parentElement.removeChild(NodeThree);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = (new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Part 2

```js
var xml = '<MainNode><NodeOne>one</NodeOne><NodeTow>tow</NodeTow><NodeThree>Three</NodeThree><NodeFour>Four</NodeFour></MainNode>',
    doc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml'),
    MainNode = doc.querySelector('MainNode'),
    NodeTow = doc.querySelector('NodeTow'),
    NodeThree = doc.querySelector('NodeThree'),
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    children;

MainNode.removeChild(NodeTow);
MainNode.removeChild(NodeThree);

children = [].slice.call(MainNode.children);
children.forEach(function (child) {
    fragment.appendChild(child);
});

doc.removeChild(MainNode);
doc.appendChild(fragment);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = (new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```